# Spinner in dialog - NullPointerException

Tags: android, dialog, spinner

I want to show custom dialog with a spinner. Strangely enough, I get NullPointerException when I try to set the adapter of the spinner...

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this.getApplicationContext());
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_spinner);

ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] {"0","1","2"});

spin = (Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinQ);
//What am I doing wrong here?
spin.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

dialog.setTitle("Questions");
dialog.show();
```

The xml layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="10dip"
>

<Spinner 
android:id="@+id/spinQ" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/> 


</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
        AlertDialog alertDialog;


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_spinner,
                                       (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root));

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] {"0","1","2"});
        spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinQ);
        //I get the error in the following line:
        spin.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setView(layout);
        alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `Spinner` is probably not inflated yet. If you want to manipulate the views, inflate it yourself and then use `setContentView` on the inflated `View`. See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) on Creating Dialogs.

**Update:**

In your new code, change:

```
spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinQ);
```

to:

```
spin = (Spinner) layout.findViewById(R.id.spinQ);
```

Comment: What about this tutorial? http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/05/spinner-view-android-beginner-dev.html

Comment: Dialogs work different from Activities, especially in terms of their lifecycles. The tutorial used the `Spinner` from the onCreate of the Activity where the View was already inflated. You might be able to do something similar and create/set the adapter in one of the Spinner's callbacks (maybe onAttachedToWindow?) but I can't say I'm too familiar with those.

Comment: I tried the example in your link, the one which use the LayoutInflater (the last example), and I still get the same error at the same position "spin.setAdapter(...)"

Comment: You're saying you inflated the View and you got `null` back? Maybe update your post and append your new code with the inflating.

Comment: Ok, that solved the problem of nullpointerexception, but now I get error with alertDialog.show() "token null is not for an application".. How do I show this alertDialog?

Comment: I replaced getApplicationContext() with this and it worked... Thanks of your help, I really appreciate it!