# Spinner in Dialog - NullPointerException - Android

Tags: android, spinner, android-alertdialog, android-spinner, customdialog

I want to show a custom dialog with a spinner in it. But when i do I get NullPointerException at the setAdapter() method.I have been trying for over a week now and couldnt figure out how to get this right. here's my code:

```
     AlertDialog alertDialog;

     LayoutInflater inflater = 
                 (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);                          
     View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form,
                                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

     ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
           android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[] {"0","1","2"});
     Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    //I get the error in the following line:

    try{ 

         spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

    }catch(Exception exception){
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    "Exception: "+exception,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

     AlertDialog.Builder  builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     builder.setView(layout);
     alertDialog = builder.create();
     alertDialog.setTitle("Security");
     alertDialog.show();
   }
```

Here's the xml file form.xml:

```
  ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:id="@+id/layout_root" >


   <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Please help me out. I've followed the link : [Spinner in dialog - NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365268/spinner-in-dialog-nullpointerexception)
which discusses the same problem but i still couldnt do it.

Comment: You need to add Spinner View dynamically/programmatically in your activity class code, and set context of this to your activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`Spinner spinner = (Spinner)layout.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);`

Comment: @vickey: A small suggestion for you ,google first on your before posting any question .It will save a lot time of yours .

Comment: getting error : The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type R.layout

Answer (score 2):

`Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);`  you can't do this here.  You need to use `layout.findviewById(...)..` (I hope your layout_root has spinner).